# The compatibility of a linear connection

Tags: differential-geometry

How to show that if a linear connection is compatible with the given metric, $i.e. \forall X,Y,Z$ smooth vector fields,  $X \langle Y, Z \rangle = \langle \nabla_X Y, Z \rangle + \langle Y, \nabla_X Z \rangle$, then $\forall$ vector fields $M,N$ along a curve $\gamma$, $\frac{d}{dt} \langle M,N\rangle = \langle D_tM, N\rangle+\langle M, D_tN\rangle$?

A straightforward approach that I can come up with is take $X$ to be $\dot \gamma$, and $Y,Z$ to be $M,N$. However, this is very problematic because $\dot \gamma$ and $M,N$ might not be able to be extended to a vector field on the given manifold.